# Is this a blisk?

Tags: turbine, engine-design

GE Aviation bought the Czech company Walther to get their 600-800shp turboprop engines, now called the H75... On their website, two thirds down the page, the following [picture](https://www.ge.com/reports/czech-mate-this-advanced-turboprop-engine-could-create-a-40-billion-market/) has the caption

> The H-series engines use blisks made from a single piece for the engine’s two axial compressor stages reduces component weight and part complexity

[image]

Is this a blisk?

Comment: 100% not a blisk. I work with them on a daily bases. That is a disc with blades.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From Wikipedia's [blisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blisk):

> A blisk (portmanteau of **bl**aded d**isk**) is a turbomachine component comprising both rotor disk and blades. It consists of a single part, instead of an assembly of a disk and individual, removable blades. Blisks may be additive manufactured, integrally cast, machined from a solid piece of material, or made by welding individual blades to a rotor disk. The term is used mainly in aerospace engine design. Blisks may also be known as integrally bladed rotors (IBR).

[image]

*Figure 1. This device is clearly made up of many pieces.*

I can't see how this could fit the Wikipedia definition so as far as they are concerned this is not a blisk.

Comment: Your cited definition says blisks may be "made by welding individual blades to a rotor disk.". You need to provide a source that shows these blades are removable, and not permanently fastened, now or at some later stage in the process.

Comment: For comparison [here](https://www.ge.com/reports/this-machine-can-cut-titanium-like-a-hot-knife-through-butter/) is a one-piece blisk.

Comment: @user71659: I don't think I need to do anything. Feel free to copy and improve.

Comment: @user71659 them blades are very clearly not welded. Once a blisk is welded and cleaned up you'd never know it wasn't once separate bits of metal. You also don't use the dovetail design for a welding blade's foot, you use it on removable blades.